# Exporting/saving annotations and highlights for DRM-free book on Kindle Fire

Tags: kindle, drm, annotations, kindle-fire

I have a DRM-free book on my Kindle Fire that I’d like to annotate, but before I make that effort I want to make sure I can save/export the annotations and highlights. So far as I can tell, this is in fact not possible, but I wanted to check here first before giving up and looking for an alternative.

Here’s the sequence that led me to conclude that there’s no way to export notes, highlights, and other annotations:

- I first made a test annotation with a unique string that’s easy to search for.
- I then connected my Fire using a USB cable and used Android File Transfer to copy the entire `Documents` folder to my macOS desktop.
- Finally, I used the `grep` utility on my Mac to search for the unique string. It doesn’t appear in any of the files. Furthermore, the `My Clippings.txt` file mentioned by some references doesn’t exist. (This may be the case for all Kindle Fires.)

Any help would be much appreciated, even if it’s only confirmation that what I want to do is impossible.